# jQueryUI AutoComplete Remote Source misdirected

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a jQuery AutoComplete for a text box. The code to initialize the AutoComplete is:

```
$("#SearchBox1").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: false,
    source: "Home/AutoComplete",
    select: function (event, ui) {
    alert(ui.item.label);
    }
```

When the URL doesn't contain a path, the jQuery Autocomplete works, but when the URL contains something like `localhost/home/GoToPage/?page=2`, then AutoComplete attempts to use `/home/GoToPage/Home/AutoComplete`. At this point AutoComplete is completely broken, because it is using a bad path.

Are there any good ways of dealing with this problem?

Comment: I don't really get the context. Do you change the source "on-the-fly" or ou are talking about two autocomplete instance with two different sources ?

Comment: you can try to use function instead of url in 'source' parameter

Comment: @DidierGhys -- The source shouldn't change. There is only one AutoComplete source on the server, and the jQueryUI AutoComplete should always point to the same source. The problem is, the source it uses does change, to an invalid URL.

Comment: @MadRabbit -- Can you explain what you mean by "use function?". Are you suggesting "create a function that does the ajax call, then returns the results from the server?"

Comment: @sveatch42 exactly, for example `source: function(request, callback){ $.get('/url/with/parameters?term=' + request.term, callback); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is based off of MadRabbit's comments, and Dan Wellman jQueryUI Autocomplete tutorial at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/

```
$("#SearchBox1").autocomplete({
        autoFocus: false,
        source: function (request, callback) {
            //pass request to server  
            $.getJSON("Home/AutoComplete?term=" + request.term, request, function (responseData) {

                //create array for response objects  
                var suggestions = [];

                //process response  
                $.each(responseData, function (i, val) {
                    suggestions.push(val);
                });
                //pass array to callback  
                callback(suggestions);
            });            
        },       
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#SearchBox1').val(ui.item.label);                           
    }
});
```